# MAXDOP or 1 only? Or sql can use a value between 1 and configured maxdop

Tags: sql-server, optimization, maxdop

Is there a way for sql server to use no of cores which is between 1 and the configured MAXDOP?

For example if maxdop is 8. Is it possible for sql to use 3? Lets say that resource gov, hints, and any other control mechanisms are not in place.

Or is it simple 1 for singlethreaded and 8 for parellelized?

Comment: What you can do is setting a query hint for your specific query. If you know that your query will for sure use the maximum 8 cores you can now limit it using the query hint. The hint is:  OPTION (MAXDOP 2) . you can find more about it here : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

When you set `MAXDOP = 8` this is not saying that the Degree of Parallelism will be 8 cores for your process.  It means that **no more** than 8 cores will be used for your process.

It could use only 1 core up to 8 cores with that setting.  This all depends on many other usage factors such as when several long processes are running on your server.  The SQL Server tries to manage the processes so that every running process gets some CPU time allocated to it very regularly.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/many-cpus-parallel-query-using-sql-server/

Brent's post also verifies that Paul White has audited Kendra Little's post as correct. (Just in case you want more verification.)

Again from Paul White from a discussion at http://www.sqlservercentral.com:

> The instance-wide `MAXDOP` setting sets the *maximum possible degree of
>   parallelism.* A setting of zero (the default) allows SQL Server to use
>   as many threads as there are processor cores that it is configured to
>   use.
>
> The *cost threshold for parallelism* is only used by the optimizer. 
>   If the cost threshold is set to 5, the query must have an estimated cost of
>   *at least 5* before the optimizer will look for a parallel plan
>   alternative.

In a case like that a `MAXDOP 8` setting for the query may not exceed the *cost threshold* and thus will not create a parallel plan.

If you have a process where you specifically need to manage resources, more than 1 but less than the `MAXDOP` setting, you could add the `OPTION (MAXDOP 4)` (as an example) or some other setting that would fit the process you are running.

Therefore, you have some choices and are not stuck with just: 1 core, 8 cores, or "all" processors.

Comment: Hi RLF, that's what i believe so far until i read this KB, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2806535. Which states "SQL Server uses a serial plan, it will use only one processor. However, if SQL Server uses parallelism, it must use all the configured processors (as determined by the MAXDOP query hint configuration"

Comment: And "For example, if you use MAXDOP=0 on a 32-way server, SQL Server tries to use all 32 processors even if 7 processors might perform the job more efficiently compared with a serial plan". So know i am trying to get more comments related to the topic.

Comment: Would you kou know any other internals doc commenting or explaining the details?

Comment: @HumpreyCogay - Added a couple of details on **MAXDOP** and **cost threshold values**.

Comment: I have personally seen a query go parallel and not use the limit set by maxdop.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188611(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

@HumpreyCogay - Bob Dorr has a great write up on the internals

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/02/13/how-it-works-sql-server-per-query-degree-of-parallelism-worker-counts/

To nitpick, MAXDOP doesn't control the number of cores directly.  It controls the number of threads used PER OPERATOR of a query plan.